# Access GoogleApiClient instance from wearable listener service failed

Tags: android, wear-os, google-api-client

I want to access the GoogleApiClient from a WearableListenerService and I got a `NullPointerException`.

The wearable listener service runs in background and listen for wear messages. On wear message reception, the service will for example call a webservice and use the GoogleApiClient for sending the response asynchronouslly to the wear.

I've tried the same code in an Activity without error. But I don't want to put this background service in an activity.

So what is the best way to do this simple communication pattern ?

Here is my code :

```
public class WearMessageListenerService extends WearableListenerService {

    private GoogleApiClient client;
    private String nodeId;

    public WearMessageListenerService(){

        client = getGoogleApiClient(this);
    }

    private GoogleApiClient getGoogleApiClient(Context context) {

        return new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context).addApi(Wearable.API).build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) { //...}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to move it to service onCreate. This sample works fine with my service

```
 @Override
public void onCreate() {

    super.onCreate();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with last anwser, or another way is:

Your can connect a google api client in `OnDataChangedMethod`, use `googleapiclient.blockConnect`

Answer (score 0):

I do this

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {

    super.onCreate();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

}
```

But when get **onStartCommand**
mGoogleApiClient  is not connected